# Power B.I - create a measure to add rows with "yes" value

Tags: powerbi

I have a column with "Yes" or "No" values in it and I want to count the number of rows with "yes". I can create a new column and have values =1 or 0 depending on the "Yes" or "No" value in the other column and then create a measure to add those values but this seems like a two step approach where there should be just a one step similar to a SUMIF text = "yes" rule in excel.

Anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No need for additional columns, try the following measure:

```
Count Yes = 
   CALCULATE(
      COUNTROWS([table]), 
      FILTER(
         [table],
         [Yes-No-Column] = "Yes"
      )
   )
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a measure:

```
Count Yes = 
    CALCULATE ( 
        COUNTROWS ( MyTable ),
        MyTable[YesNo] = "Yes"
    ) + 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume the table is called "ABC", and column where yes/no values is called "yes/no", then this DAX formula will take care of your scenario:

`Measure :=
COUNTX ( FILTER ( ABC, ABC[yes/no] = "yes" ), ABC[yes/no] )`

Answer (score 0):

I kept getting an error message when testing the Yes/No column against "Yes" ... so I tried this instead, and it worked ...

```
MyMeasure = 
    CALCULATE ( 
        COUNTROWS (MyDataSource),
        MyDataSource[YesNoColumn] = TRUE()
    ) + 0
```